# Check if a row with specific td exists on a table jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to check if a row that has td with specific title and year.
Here is my function and the problem is the title2 and year2 are set to undefined.
How do I get cell values correctly?

```
var table = $("#mainTable");
        var exist;
        $(table).find("tr").each(function () {
            var title2 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").html();
            var year2 = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").html();
            if (title == title2 && year == year2)
                exist = true;

        });
        return exist;
```

and my table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="mainTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Emri</th>
                <th scope="col">Viti</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var subject in Model.Subjects)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td id="subjectId">@subject.Id</td>
                    <td id="subjectTitle">@subject.Title</td>
                    <td id="subjectYear"> @subject.Year</td>
                    <td>
                        <a id="add" class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                        <a id="edit" class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                        <a id="delete" class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You appear to be re-using `id` attribute values within a loop. Don't do that; `id` attributes must be unique within the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably due to including `<thead>` row in your loop which has no `<td>`

Also `nth-child` is not zero based so you are looking in wrong cells

Try searching only the `<tbody>` rows by changing to

```
    var table = $("#mainTable");
    var exist;
    table.find("tbody tr").each(function () {
        var title2 = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html();
        var year2 = $(this).find("td:eq(2)").html();
        if (title == title2 && year == year2)
            exist = true;
            // break the loop once found
            return false;

    });
    return exist;
```

Finally, element id's are unique by definition. Use common classes instead

Answer (score 2):

just a suggestion since it appears you are already creating your table using razor why not add data attributes of title and year to each row.  then you can just use a selector.

```
 $(`tr[data-title='three'][data-year='2017']`).css('background-color', 'green');
```

here is a fiddle demonstrating ( I used javascript instead of razor to create the table but you get the idea)

https://jsfiddle.net/xtqnksj4/